# How can I bind a sudoku grid with Kendo?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am building a sudoku game in Javascript with Kendo UI. I am trying to value bind my data structure representing the 9 by 9 Sudoku grid to 81 divs. How can I do this without creating 81 properties on my model and writing data-bind="value:board.atXY" 81 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid widget won't easily work in this case. I suggest using the list view instead.

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 81; i++) {
  data.push({ value: i });
}

$("#listview").kendoListView({
  dataSource: data,
  template: "<div>#= value #</div>"
});
```

With some CSS you can style it to look like a grid: http://jsbin.com/evUnufA/1/edit